# Proof Check: The union of two linearly independent sets is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces, independence

Let U and V be two subspaces of a vector space E such that $U ∩ V = \{0\}$. Prove that if $X ⊆ U$ and $Y ⊆ V$ are two linearly independent sets then so is $X \cup Y$.

So I believe I have a good start, but it may not hold (I'm still a beginner at conducting proofs..). Feel free to critique wherever necessary!

**Origonal Proof**:

$X$ and $Y$ are linearly independent. Thus, they do not contain the $0$ element. 
$X$ is a subset of $U$ and $Y$ is a subset of $V$, and $V \cap U = \{0\}$, so $X \cap Y = \{\emptyset\}$. (So, for any $ x \in X \cup Y$, $x \neq 0 $)

Suppose $X\cup Y$ is linearly dependent.

So, there exists $x \in X\cup Y$ and $y \in X\cup Y$ such that $x = y$ and they exist in the linear combination of other elements $\in X \cup Y$.

i.e. $ x = (\lambda a + \mu b) =y $ for $a, b \in X \cup Y$ and scalers $\lambda$ and $\mu$ in the Field.

If $ (\lambda a + \mu b) = 0$, then we are done, for $x \neq 0 \neq y$.

Let $ (\lambda a + \mu b) \neq 0$. (Note: $a \neq 0 \neq b$, and $\lambda \neq 0 \neq \mu$)

Then $a$ and $b$ are in a linearly independent set, so $X \cup Y$ is linearly independent.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5):

Suppose $X \cup Y$ is not linearly independent.

So, there exists $x_1, ... ,x_n \in X $ and $y_1, ..., y_n \in Y$ s.t. $\lambda_1 x_1 + ... + \lambda_n x_n + \alpha_1 y_1 +...+ \alpha_n y_n = 0$.

$\lambda_1 x_1 + ... + \lambda_n x_n = -(\alpha_1 y_1 +...+ \alpha_n y_)$

$(\lambda_1 x_1 + ... + \lambda_n x_n) \in$ $span(X)$, which is contained in $U$, since U is a subspace.

$-(\alpha_1 y_1 +...+ \alpha_n y_) \in$ $span(Y)$ which is in $V$, similarly.

But $span(U \cap V)=\{0\}$, so the only solution to $\lambda_1 x_1 + ... + \lambda_n x_n = -(\alpha_1 y_1 +...+ \alpha_n y_)$ is if all of the scalers, $\lambda$ and $\alpha$ are $=0$

thus shows linear independence in $X \cup Y$

Answer (score 4):

I think much of what you write is going around in circles. Rather than correct the errors, I'd suggest a different start.

Suppose that union is not linearly independent. Then there is some nontrivial linear combination of the vectors in $X \cup Y$ that is $0$. Rewrite that so that it shows that a combination of the vectors in $X$ is equal to a combination of the vectors in $Y$, so is in the span of each, so is in $U \cap V$.

What can you conclude from that? How does it contradict the linear independence of $X$ or $Y$?

Comment: Ok, this really helped me reflect on it all. This is what I now have:

Suppose $X \cup Y$ is not linearly independent. So, there exists $x_1,x_2 \in X$ and $y_1, y_2 \in Y$ s.t. $\lambda x_1 + \mu x_2 = \alpha y_1 + \beta y_2$. So, these combinations are thus in the span of $X \cap Y$, which is contained in the span of $U \cap V = \{0\}$, so the span of $X \cap Y$ is 0. Thus you can conclude that all of the scalers are zero, thus $X \cup Y$ is lin. ind. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Pascal Almost. You don't know that the linear combination involves exactly two vectors from each of $X$ and $Y$. At the end you don't need the span of $X \cup Y$, you need the fact that the span of $X$ is part of $U \cap V$ so the left hand side of your equality must be $0$. Then you have to use the fact that $X$ is independent to conclude ...

Comment: Ok, this brings me to this:

There exists $(x_1, ... , x_n)$ and $(y_1,...,y_n)$ $\in X\cup Y$ such that $\alpha_1 x_1+...+\alpha_n x_n + \lambda_1 y_1 + ... + \lambda_n y_n = 0$ for not all scalers equal to 0. But then I am stuck, for I cannot use the linear independence of X or of Y because none of these elements are strictly in X or strictly in Y nor can I use the fact that these scalers are in the span of X or Y...

Comment: Put the $x$'s on one side and the $y$'s on the other to get a vector in the intersection $Z$  of the span of $X$ and the span of $Y$. But $Z$ is part of $U \cap V = \{0\}$. Now you know the combination of the $x$'s is $0$ but the $x$'s are independent so the $\alpha$'s are all $0$.

Comment: Ok, I kept thinking that I couldn't do that because there may exist an element in the Linear combination that isn't strictly in X or strictly in Y. I don't have to worry about that? Is that because $X \cap Y = \{\emptyset\}$?

Comment: Those combinations may not be in $X$ itself - they hardly ever are if $X$ is finite. But you don't need them to be in $X$. What you need to finish the proof is that they are in $U$.

Comment: You should edit your question to remove the answer, and post it separately as an answer to the question. (You are allowed to answer your own questions here.) Also: you don't need $\text{span } U$, just $U$, since you're told $U$ is a subspace.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry; I can't follow your proof at all.

What you always want to do when proving results about linear (in)dependence is to recall how dependence is defined: that some linear combination of elements, not all coefficients zero, gives the zero vector. Suppose some such combination exists with elements of $X\cup Y$. The parts of the sum due to the respective elements of $X,\,Y$ are then some two vectors summing to zero, say $v$ and $-v$.

By thinking about which vector spaces $v$ provably lives in, can you prove $v=0$? By the linear independence of $X$, what does that tell you about some coefficients? Similarly with $Y$; what does that tell you about the other coefficients?

Comment: Thank you, love the input- it is insightful. I tend to overthink proofs, so someone telling me to slow down and remember what it takes to to prove ____ and the questions I should be asking myself